# How to use handle multiple fragment to use method

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have method select() was defined in class DBHelper that extend SQLiteOpenHelper , in MainActivity I initiated the dtabases variable dbHelper :

```
 DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this, "DB");
```

I have 4 fragments each one need to call the method select() , How to do that ?? 
second in each fragment do I need to do the definition of the dbHelper in each fragment or is there a way to get it from the MainActivity in other words defined it once.

```
 DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(getActivity(), "DBTEST");
        SQLiteDatabase db =dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
```

This is the select() method :

```
public Cursor selectdb(String tsql) {     
        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(getActivity(), "DBTest");
        SQLiteDatabase db =dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(tsql, null);
        db.close();
        return c;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this recipe:

1. define an interface for retrieving the `DBHelper`:

   ```
   public interface DBHelperSource {
       DBHelper getDBHelper();
   }
   ```
2. Declare your activity to implement the interface and implement the method to return your activity's `DBHelper` object.

   ```
   public class MyActivity extends Activity implements DBHelperSource {
       ...
       private DBHelper mDBHelper;

       @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           mDBHelper = new DBHelper(this, "DBTest");
           ...
       }

       @Override public DBHelper getDBHelper() {
           return mDBHelper;
       }
       ...
   }
   ```
3. In each fragment's `onAttach(Context)` method, cast the context to `DBHelperSource`, retrieve the `DBHelper` object, and stash it in an instance variable for that fragment.

   ```
   public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
       private DBHelper mDBHelper;

       ...

       @Override public void onAttach(Context context) {
           super.onAttach(context);
           if (context instanceof DBHelperSource) {
               mDBHelper = ((DBHelperSource) context).getDBHelper();
           }
       }

       @Override public void onDetach() {
           super.onDetach();
           mDBHelper = null;
       }
   }
   ```

For more information on this pattern, see the Android tutorial [Communicating with Other Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

There's one little gotcha: if there's a chance that the fragment is attached before the activity instantiates the `DBHelper` object, then you'd probably want to alter the above as follows. Instead of initializing a `DBHelper` field in `onAttach()`, just store the `DBHelperSource` object itself as a field. Then only call `getDBHelper()` when you need the `DBHelper` object itself (i.e., just when you're ready to call `select()`).

Another approach is to just define the interface to contain the `select` method itself, and don't bother communicating the `DBHelper` object to the fragments. Of course, this only works if the logic is identical among all four fragments.

Comment: Thank you for quick responding , how about the dbHelper variable that I defined it in mainactivity , can I use it with the other fragment , or I need to make new DBHelper(getActivity(), "DBTEST"); with each fragment that will access the DB.

Comment: @Mi_Dhah - You should be able to reuse it.

Comment: And if it possible can you please write the code when the mainactivity implement the interface , I confused with the " return your activity's  DBHelper object."